# Why was Will not affected by the Aztec curse?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean

How did Will Turner not turn into a zombie when he was a child, when his father left him the last Aztec golden piece?

Answer (score 12):

The implication is that the curse only applies to those who initially removed the gold from the chest. Those who were paid with the coins, or acquired them through other circumstances, were exempted because they did not remove the gold themselves.

Comment: You might want to mention that it isn't literal physical removal as well, but also anyone who agreed or went along with the thievery. I saw some comments in the other question mentioning how the captain might not have let them each take their share directly from the chest. He probably carried it back and then divided up the shares.